# AttributeError: module 'h5py' has no attribute 'file'

Tags: python, h5py

```
h5f_data = h5py.file('output/data.h5', 'w')  
AttributeError: module 'h5py' has no attribute 'file'
```

It's my first time working with `h5py`. I search about it everywhere but didn't get the solution. It will be very helpful if you can provide me with the solution.

Comment: `h5py.File(name)` - capitalized

Comment: done but giving the same problem

Comment: You are writing a file. Does directory/folder `output/` exist in the  location where you're executing the script? Try without the directory/folder name.

Answer (score 0):

**Follow following steps:**

1. pip uninstall h5py
2. conda install h5py

Comment: the conda version is even worse & crashes on loading the module