# `h5py.File` bug: `AttributeError: module 'h5py' has no attribute 'File'`

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, tensorflow2.0, h5py

I'm trying to run my GPU instead of CPU in `Jupyter Notebook`. My `GPU` works now. However, I'm getting an error as in the snippet below.I've tried virtually every to fix that `h5py` missing file [**bug**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55171349/attributeerror-module-h5py-has-no-attribute-file?rq=2), but I haven't succeeded. That essentially means that in my `activate envGPU4` I cannot run some code. I was reasoning along the lines that some `h5py` file overwrites that system one, but I'm unable to fix it.From `Anaconda` it does work somehow:

```
(C:\Users\Documents\myenvGPU4) C:\Users\Documents>python -c "import h5py; print(h5py.__file__)"
C:\Users\Documents\myenvGPU4\lib\site-packages\h5py\__init__.py
```

Gives this output:

```
C:\Users\Documents\myenvGPU4\lib\site-packages\h5py\__init__.py
```

and

```
 python -c "import h5py; print(h5py.__version__)"
 3.10.0
```

*But not in the Jupyter Notebook!*

[image]

**EDIT**
The initial code was like this:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.applications import MobileNetV2
from tensorflow.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image

# Load the pre-trained MobileNetV2 model
model = MobileNetV2(weights='imagenet', include_top=True)

# Load and preprocess an image
# Replace 'path/to/your/image.jpg' with the actual file path
img_path = 'path/to/your/image.jpg'
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))  # MobileNetV2 expects images of size 224x224
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = preprocess_input(x)

# Make a prediction
predictions = model.predict(x)

# Decode and print the top-3 predicted classes
for _, pred_class, prob in decode_predictions(predictions, top=3)[0]:
    print(f"Predicted: {pred_class} with probability {prob}")
```

**EDIT 2** Also with Anaconda terminal it doesn't work:

```
root@2:~# /mnt/c/Users//Documents/myenvGPU3/python.exe  ./a
2023-12-25 19:07:55.247085: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not f
2023-12-25 19:07:55.247284: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
WARNING:root:Limited tf.compat.v2.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
WARNING:root:Limited tf.compat.v2.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
WARNING:root:Limited tf.compat.v2.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
WARNING:root:Limited tf.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
WARNING:root:Limited tf.compat.v2.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
WARNING:root:Limited tf.compat.v2.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
WARNING:root:Limited tf.compat.v2.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
2023-12-25 19:07:56.445709: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not f
2023-12-25 19:07:56.446225: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cublas64_11.dll'; dlerror: cublas64_11.dll not fou
2023-12-25 19:07:56.446665: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cublasLt64_11.dll'; dlerror: cublasLt64_11.dll not
2023-12-25 19:07:56.447011: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cufft64_10.dll'; dlerror: cufft64_10.dll not found
2023-12-25 19:07:56.447354: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'curand64_10.dll'; dlerror: curand64_10.dll not fou2023-12-25 19:07:56.447723: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cusolver64_11.dll'; dlerror: cusolver64_11.dll not
2023-12-25 19:07:56.448077: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cusparse64_11.dll'; dlerror: cusparse64_11.dll not
2023-12-25 19:07:56.448397: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudnn64_8.dll'; dlerror: cudnn64_8.dll not found
2023-12-25 19:07:56.448491: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1934] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above
Skipping registering GPU devices...
2023-12-25 19:07:56.448812: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use t
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu-22.04\root\a", line 8, in <module>
    model = MobileNetV2(weights='imagenet', include_top=True)
  File "C:\Users\Documents\myenvGPU3\lib\site-packages\keras\applications\mobilenet_v2.py", line 484, in MobileNetV2
    model.load_weights(weights_path)
  File "C:\Users\Documents\myenvGPU3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\Documents\myenvGPU3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 2931, in load_weights
    with h5py.File(filepath, "r") as f:
AttributeError: module 'h5py' has no attribute 'File'
```