# Problem when save model during training using Tensorflow-gpu. I got this error: AttributeError: module 'h5py' has no attribute 'File'

Tags: tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, h5py

I got this Problem when save model during training using Tensorflow-gpu. I got this error: AttributeError: module 'h5py' has no attribute 'File'.Plss help me!!!!

I had try uninstall and reinstall h5py package but it still not working.
Here is the path to save weight:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZfEo.png)
Here is code train model:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umO6z.png)
And here is the error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McPtU.png)

Comment: Someone else had a similar error last week, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77714431/h5py-file-bug-attributeerror-module-h5py-has-no-attribute-file.  `File` is such a basic `h5py` function, that I suspect the `h5py` that you import is not the real thing.  But I can't explore your import.  Is there anything else in the module matches the h5py docs?